# How to only pass non-empty variables as function parameters?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I have a function that will always receive 3 arguments; at least one arg will have a value, but one or more may not. After working with the arguments in this function, I need to send only the arguments with values to another function. Furthermore, the second function needs at least 2 args, so I only want to execute it if at least 2 of my args have a value. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Here is an example of my code structure:

```
function doSomething(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    // Do something with args

    // Only want to send args with values to this function (min 2 args)
    return doSomethingElse(arg1, arg2, arg3);

}
```

**Edit:** The second function, `doSomethingElse()`, can receive any number of args with a minimum of 2.

Comment: So how would it work? it would be `doSomethingElse(arg1, arg3);` if 2 had no value?

Comment: Filter the *arguments* list for non empty values, and apply the resulting array to the second function,  but only if it is at least 2 items long.

Comment: @epascarello Yes

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) with an array so you can pass what you want.

```
function doSomething() {

  // convert the arguments to an array
  var args = Array.from(arguments);
  // var args = [...arguments]; // or use spread operator

  // filter the array with only thing that are not undefined (change your check)
  var  argsWithValues = args.filter(function (item) { return item !== undefined })
  // const argsWithValues = args.filter(item = > item !== undefined)

  // call function if there are 2 items or more
  return argsWithValues.length > 1 ? doSomethingElse.apply(this, argsWithValues) : null;

}
```

Comment: It would look nice if you split this into two possibilities, ES5 and ES6, instead of the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You first filter the `arguments` object to ensure that there are no `undefined` values. From there you can pass the arguments object (via `spread`) into the next function if there are two or more.

```js
function doSomething(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
  const totalArgs = [...arguments].filter(arg => arg !== undefined);

  if (totalArgs.length >= 2) {
    return doSomethingElse(...totalArgs);
  } else {
    console.log('Not enough arguments supplied');
  }
}

function doSomethingElse() {
  Array.from(arguments).forEach(arg => console.log(arg));
}

// doSomethingElse() fires
doSomething(1,2);
// doSomethingElse() doesn't fire. Not enough arguments.
doSomething(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [rest operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters):

```js
function one(...args) {
  console.log(args.length);
  two(...args);
}

function two(...args) {
  console.log(args.length);
}

one(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
function doSomething(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    // Do something with args

    // Only want to send args with values to this function (min 2 args)
    if ([arg1, arg2, arg3].filter(arg => null != arg).length >= 2) {
        return doSomethingElse(arg1, arg2, arg3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope that help you.

```
function doSomething() {
    // Do something with args
    if(arguments.length==0){
      console.error("this function should have a param");return;
    }
    var args = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
          console.log("argument number " + i + " : "  + arguments[i]); args.push(arguments[i]);
    }
    // Only want to send args with values to this function (min 2 args)
    return doSomethingElse(args);

}
function doSomethingElse(){
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
          console.log("argument number " + i + " : "  + arguments[i]);
    }
}
```